# VBA - Double click event to unhide Rows only until the matching text in a column

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to modify this such that it can work on any Active Cell, within a column Range on a double click event?

ie: when double clicking on any cell within Range(C:C), It searches from the Active Cell down until meets a cell containing data same as Active cell

It un-hides all the rows between the Active Cell and the one with data?
(ex: Active Cell = Data1 until other Data1 it should unhide the rows)

Excel Looks like:

[image]

Output should be, when double click on Data1 cell it should unhide the rows of Data1 only.

Required Output:

[image]

Can something like this be done?

I was able to get only for empty cells in the below code but not as per my requirement.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

If Application.Intersect(Target, Range("C:C")) Is Nothing Then Cancel = True: Exit Sub

    'if there is no cell with a value below the clicked cell then cancel
    If Cells.Rows.Count = Target.End(xlDown).Row Then Cancel = True _
        Else Range(Target.Offset(1, 0), Target.End(xlDown).Offset(-1, 0)).Rows.Hidden = False

End Sub
```

Comment: Your question seems a bit conflicted, do you want to unhide all the rows between your selected cell and the next match cell, or all the rows that match the value of your selected cell?

Comment: When i double click on Data1 cell it should unhide 2 & 3 rows conatining only Data1. It should not unhide Data2 bur when i click on Data2  only unhide rows containing Data2.